# Object already owned exception on Esri Native Xamarin Android

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, esri

I want to display downloaded layers on the map. The map which I am using is also an offline Esri map. The problem is that when I am adding layers on the map using `myMap.OperationalLayers.Add();`. I am getting an Exception i.e `Object already owned`.

Code:

```
if (featureLayerDict.Any())
            {              
                // Remove the previously applied layers
                if (myMap.OperationalLayers != null)
                {                   
                    myMap.OperationalLayers.Clear();
                }

                // Select the LayerIds, which are based on if Parent Layer is selected
                var selectedMapLayerIds = mapLayers.Select(l => l.ID).ToList();
                foreach (var dictItem in featureLayerDict)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        // Add the layer to maps operational layer only if its parent layer is selected and if its present in the userlayers
                        if (userLayers.Contains(dictItem.Key) && selectedMapLayerIds.Contains(dictItem.Key))
                        {
                            myMap.OperationalLayers.Add(dictItem.Value); 
                        }
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        continue;
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: I have the same issue. Have you found solution?

Comment: New up your map view.

Comment: @TatsonBaptista what do you mean by? Do I need to create a new map view?

Comment: I too facing a similar issue, I am using 2 map views in my app, but both are in different layouts and having different Fragments. And clearing the overlays and map from map view but still, it is showing the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

A FeatureLayer can only be owned by one map at the same time. 
So after close the first map, you have to make null the references to their layers or just do:

```
myMap.OperationalLayers.Clear();
```

at the beginning of the method that adds the layers to the map.